# How to strip header tags & shortcodes from the_excerpt()

Tags: shortcode, excerpt

I'm trying to learn how to strip "header tags" & "shortcodes" from `the_excerpt()`... Searched for an answer to no avail so thought Id ask the community.

Thanks for your time

Best
Shaun

Answer (score 0):

### Remove Shortcodes

First, try this on your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'strip_shortcodes', 20 );
```

If it doesn't work then try this edit.

```
echo strip_shortcodes( get_the_excerpt() );
```

In case the shortcode is not registered with WordPress function `add_shortcode`

```
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'remove_shortcodes_in_excerpt', 20 );

function remove_shortcodes_in_excerpt( $content){
    $content = strip_shortcodes($content);
    $tagnames = array('box', 'alert');  // add shortcode tag name
    $content = do_shortcodes_in_html_tags( $content, true, $tagnames );

    $pattern = get_shortcode_regex( $tagnames );
    $content = preg_replace_callback( "/$pattern/", 'strip_shortcode_tag', $content );
    return $content;
}
```

---

### Remove Headings

Add this code to your `functions.php`

```
function wp_strip_header_tags( $text ) {

$raw_excerpt = $text;
if ( '' == $text ) {
    //Retrieve the post content.
    $text = get_the_content(''); 
    //remove shortcode tags from the given content.
    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
}
    $regex = '#(]*>)\s?(.*)?\s?()#';
    $text = preg_replace($regex,'', $text);

    /***Change the excerpt word count.***/
    $excerpt_word_count = 60; //WP default is 55
    $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count);

    /*** Change the excerpt ending.***/
    $excerpt_end = '[...]'; //This is the WP default.
    $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end);

    $excerpt = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );

    return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_strip_header_tags', 5);
```

Comment: Beautiful, I will give this a shot and report back! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, didnt have luck on the first 2 options to remove the shortcodes, but before I try the 3rd option, I need a little clarification on what the tagname array is in reference to? $tagnames = array('box', 'alert');  // add shortcode tag name ... For example, I have a Caldera form shortcode that shows up each time in my search archive... do I put the entire shortcode id there?

Comment: For example, the alert shortcode was something like [alert message="x"], so, use the shortcode name.

Comment: Hmm... it seems as though the parent theme is overriding any changes to the_excerpt no matter what I do... Im going to have to dig around and find the offending function in the parent theme I think. I do appreciate your help though. Thank you!